# How do i get one flair showing all the associated account's reputation?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, flair, combined-flair

As everybody knows, we can get the flair of a particular account by clicking on the **"got flair?"** link given below the gravatar and reputation on the account's profile.

But is there any way to get all the associated accounts' flair as the only flair (i.e., a single flair showing the combined reputation of all accounts, such as Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Area 51, Super User, etc.)?

That way, instead of copying all the flairs' coding (i.e. JavaScript), I can make one copy and paste at my site.

How can I get a flair, which shows the reputation of all my associated accounts?

Comment: Is there a reason you keep rolling back edits that have made the English in this readable?

Comment: Next time, for those under 3k and finding a dupe, just post a comment. @cro

Comment: @random: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/59553/revisions

Comment: @Jon Seigel the link which u posted, is showing an error "Page Not Found"

Comment: @random i thought this one may be one of the feature..so i tried to suggest and post...but this kind of appreciation(CLOSED) makes user more happy  to post here..right !!

Comment: Are you saying you want this dupe reopened because you asked it?

Comment: @random where is the dupe of this question ? the link posted by "Jon seigel" showing "PAge Not Found" error

Comment: The link pointed out by @jon shows your history of meaningless edits to a question that render the entire post even harder to parse. The dupe questions are listed right under the title as of this edit.

Comment: @random @Popular Demand  Ok thanx and as you people Wish

Comment: @random @Popular Demand thanx for closing, but the feature is available right now but you have closed and throwing on me as this is a wrong conceptual question and bla bla!!!